# How to synchronously find instance and create in LoopBack

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am quite new with NodeJS and it is obviously causing some problems as things have a very asynchronously nature.

I am trying to find to instances which has to be used to create a new one (relation): `countryId` and `clientId`.

Obviously things are happening asynchronously so the variables are undefined. How do i make it synchronously?

This is my boot script in LoopBack

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var Client = app.models.Client
    var Country = app.models.Country
    var BillingAddress = app.models.BillingAddress

    Client.create([
        {username: 'test@test.gov', email: 'test@test.gov', password: 'nasapassword'},
        {username: 'test2@test2.gov', email: 'test2@test2.gov', password: 'nanapassword'}
    ], function(err, clients){
        if(err) throw err
    })


    Country.findOne({where: {name: 'Spain'}},
        function(err, country) {
            if(err) throw err
        }
    )

    Client.findOne({where: {email: 'john@nasa.gov'}},
        function(err, client) {
            if(err) throw err
        }
    )

    BillingAddress.create([
        {first_name: 'Jimbo', last_name: 'Juice', address_line_1: 'Loool street', postal_code: '23232', countryId: country.id, clientId: client.id}
    ], function(err, billingaddress) {
        if(err) throw err

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The async function should be treated as an async call.

You can use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module.

```
module.exports = function(app, cb) {
    var Client = app.models.Client;
    var Country = app.models.Country;
    var BillingAddress = app.models.BillingAddress;

var clientData = [{username: 'test@test.gov', email: 'test@test.gov', password: 'nasapassword'},
        {username: 'test2@test2.gov', email: 'test2@test2.gov', password: 'nanapassword'}];

async.parallel({
  clients: function(callback){
    async.map(clientData, Client.create.bind(Client), function(err, clients){
      if(err) return callback(err);
      callback(null, clients);
    });    
  },
  country: function(callback){
    Country.findOne({where: {name: 'Spain'}}, callback);
  },
  nasaClient: function(callback){
    Client.findOne({where: {email: 'john@nasa.gov'}}, callback);
  }
}, function(err, results){
     if(err) return cb(err);

   BillingAddress.create([
        {first_name: 'Jimbo', last_name: 'Juice', address_line_1: 'Loool street', postal_code: '23232', countryId: results.country.id, clientId: results.nasaClient.id}
    ], function(err, billingaddress) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null);
    });
});

}
```

Some points :

- The boot script should be async too
- Avoid throwing exceptions. Just handle it by `callback`s

Comment: So i included "async" and i get following error when i run the code `TypeError: this.getDataSource is not a function`

Comment: @JavaCake Where do you use `this.getDataSource `?

Comment: The project is literally new, and i am running in-memory db.

Comment: @JavaCake For ensuring, have you install `async`? Have you run `npm install` before running your project?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.5",

Comment: And i have indeed run `npm install`

Comment: @JavaCake Can you put your code in gist or github if it's not secret?

Comment: Everything else is default in my project.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/pantaluna/loopback-sandbox-this-getdatasource/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @JavaCake I updated my answer. There was a problem in using `async.map`.

Comment: I corrected the email to `test@test.gov` in the where-clause, but it seems to be the findOne that is failing in nasaClient now, it never finds that instance so the result is null.

Comment: @JavaCake It's because of `clients` and `nasaClient` run in parallel not series. Just change `parallel` method with `series` method

Comment: Perfect! Works like a glove.. I really need to get used to all this code, coming from Python ORM!

Comment: @JavaCake Cool! Would you mind kindly accept my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136971/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-javacake).